# Run exec() in PHP as a different Windows user?

Tags: php, windows, cordova, exec

I'm trying to create a Cordova project in a PHP script, using :

```
$command = "cordova create test";
exec($command);
```

This doesn't work because the `cordova` command (which is a NodeJS plugin) is only available to the normal Windows user, and not the local system account that runs the Apache service (so also not to PHP).

I found some answers on here that relate to linux, but I need this to work on Windows.

Is there a way to change the user that runs `exec()` to my normal Windows account?

***UPDATE***

After adding `C:\Users\<ACCOUNTNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the `PATH` variable it works. That's where the `cordova.cmd` file is located (on my system).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the binary available to the system account. That's it.

Comment: Yes, but how, by setting the system path from within PHP?   since cordova isn't a real executable, but a node.js plugin, I don't know which path to use